# proper way to set user's last_visit

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is the proper way to implement updating user's last visit in database?

I have column last_visit in users table and added this code to bootstrap.php file

```
protected function _initUser() {
        $this->bootstrap(array('db'));

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
        if($identity) {
            $userModel = new Model_User();
            $user_id = $identity->id;
            $userModel->updateLastVisit($user_id, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        }
    }
```

Is that good? Or should I do this diffrent way?

**EDIT**

I ended up doing this so the database is queried only once every 5 minutes. Can I leave it as it is now or are there any more changes necessary to make it work better (in performance point of view)

```
protected function _initUser() {

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $currentUser = $auth->getIdentity();
        if((time() - strtotime($currentUser->last_visit)) > 60*5) {
            $last_visit = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $currentUser->last_visit = $last_visit;
            $this->bootstrap(array('db'));
            $user = new Model_User();
            $user->updateLastVisit($currentUser->id, $last_visit);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is Ok if you have no problems with speed. Now you have a bunch of operations for each request (Even if it looks pretty simple - Zend will do a lot of work behind those two lines). And if you fight for tens of milliseconds - these lines are one of the first candidate for improvement. I do not think you need to have the latest possible value. So it can be enough to update last_visit after login or when user is logged in automatically because of "remember me" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform this kind of operation using [**plug-in hooks**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) when dispatching the request, the same way you do when checking if the user is logged in. While it works through the bootstrap class, from an architectural point of view, this is related to the [cross-cutting concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) of your application (see [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)).

You can even perform this operation within your **access check plug-in**, something similar to what @FAngel proposed: Storing the new date after logins or after grabbing the cookie,  **avoiding requesting the database every time the user reloads the page**.

Answer (score 0):

**Last login:** Update the datetime in your LoginController. Example: https://gist.github.com/2842698 (line 100), or as Keyne already said, put it in a special plug-in.

**Last visit:** We put this data temporary in a key-value storage(memached), and save the data with a cronjob each 5 minutes. So you don't have any performance issues with your DB.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated code. Do you think it's ok now?

Comment: Yes.. this is also a good solution. Note; For logical reasons I should put this piece of code in a plugin instead of your bootstrap.